# Can an apostate be forgiven by Allah?

Tags: forgiveness, apostasy

Can an apostate be forgiven by Allah?
I'm asking because of the verse [4:137](https://quran.com/4/137):

> "Those who believe, then reject faith, then believe (again) and (again) reject faith, and go on increasing in unbelief,- Allah will not forgive them nor guide them nor guide them on the way."

Answer (score 1):

Al Salam Aleikum

Repentance is accepted from anybody as long as it fulfills it's conditions,  so yes an apostate can be forgiven even he/she repents before he/she dies.

Comment: maybe quoting  3:89  would be good, also commenting on verses before (such as  3:86), which is similar to the quoted verse in the question.